# Why we have a leak in the pipe if the fluid pressure is lower than the atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

I've read in many books that if our flow pressure is lower than the atmospheric pressure then we'll have a leak in our pipe, but I already know that the flow is always from the high pressure point to the lower one. So the flow must be from outside to the pipe not from pipe to the outside, I'll be thankful if someone explains this issue by thermodynamics or fluids mechanics phenomena.

Comment: By *pressure* we often mean *pressure difference from atmospheric*. So if the pressure in a pipe is *P* this usually actually means *P + 1 atmosphere*.

Comment: That would be my guess.

Comment: @JohnRennie Hmm..so that pressure is always a "gauge" pressure?

Comment: @JohnRennie i thinks its not correct,if we take it as gauge pressure,then at "every" pressure its absolute pressure is higher than atmosphere...since we have not negative gauge pressure.

Comment: A small piece of advice: in English, we do not capitalize random words. Only the first word of each sentence, the word "I", or [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) should be capitalized.

Comment: @MoSamani You can certainly have negative gauge pressure. A classic example of a machine using negative gauge pressure is the Newcomen steam engine.

Answer (score 0):

**it depends in fact.**
if your fluid is in touch with air in two places(upside of fluid and hole place)
so although pressure of fluid is lower than air we have a flow.because the equation of pressure in that place would be
**P(air)+p(fluid)>p(air)**
the left side is the pressure which we have in the fluid in that place outwards.
the right side is the pressure which air  pushes  to wards fluid from out side.
so we have flow.
but what you say is right just the time **when fluid is not in touch with air by upside.**
the equation would be:
p(fluid)

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "upside" , Just assume we have a pipeline and a hole in the pipe,so the fluid leaks only if it has a higher absolute pressure than the surrounding. And its opposite of what i've read in thermodynamics or fluids mechs.

Comment: are you persian?

Comment: what you say is right but I said that it is possible that you have mixed up the issue with the time our fluid is in touch with air on the surface and hole point both.so the absolute pressure is not higher than the surrounding.

Comment: yes and i got the point,thanks for the instructions.